# bootstrap 2 sidebar with two links per line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-rails

what I want to do is to create a sidebar not only with one link per line, but with two links per line. I tried almost everything but there is something I'm missing and I don't know what. The links could also be an image.
Btw, I working in Rails 3.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I got this solution: just added nav-pills to my nav class for each <ul>